# FileSystemWatcher: Created event didn't fire on file creation

Tags: events, filesystemwatcher

I have one Window service, which is watching (Subscribing) a shared location on some other server as below (Using FileSystemWatcher):

```
_fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(filePath);
_fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
_fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
_fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

However, when new file was received and copied onto location, Created event didn't fire. When I restarted my service and copied file, event fired successfully.

I am trying to find answer, why event didn't fire earlier. Is it possible that if after initializing FileSystemWatcher, this is some network outage, so events wont be fired and when network is up, FileSystemWatcher needs to be reinitialized, to fire respective events? 
Also I see that there was one more service instance which was watching same share location, whose event fired successfully. Just FYI: Second service instance was started recently (Possibly network outage was during weekend).